# iPython TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Tags: ipython

*Python 2.7.10 / Anaconda / windows 8.1*

I have strange issue, the following code works on one solution file in the same working directory. 
But when I copy call the exact same code to my sheet. I get this error, so I have no idea to fix this.

Here's the code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import numpy as np
    %matplotlib inline    
    x = np.zeros(20)
    x[:5] = 10
    x[5:15] = np.arange(12,31,2)
    x[15:] = 30
    plt.plot(x)
    plt.plot([4,4],[8,32],'k--')
    plt.plot([14,14],[8,32],'k--')
    plt.ylim(8,32)


     Traceback (most recent call last)<ipython-input-65-6b573104eb1d> in <module>()
          6 plt.plot([4,4],[8,32],'k--')
          7 plt.plot([14,14],[8,32],'k--')
    ----> 8 plt.ylim(8,32)
    TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: It worked ok for me.

Comment: @maazza "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt"

Comment: @DSM thank you problem solved !